# How can one detect "useless" indexes?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a MongoDB collection with a lot of indexes.

Would it bring any benefits to delete indexes that are barely used?

Is there any way or tool which can tell me (in numbers) how often a index is used?

**EDIT:** I'm using version 2.6.4

**EDIT2:** I'm now using version 3.0.3

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/measure-index-use/

Comment: I've been there already. But I honestly don't get how this helps me.

Comment: Hmm there is no easy way, even if you code it yourself withut manually going through every query and marking the index as beng useful then deleting all those not marked

Comment: @Sammaye I'm fine with that. But HOW can I see the usage?

Comment: As I said you manually go through each query run an explain, take the index being used and print out the indexes for that collection (db.c.getIndexes()) and on a piece of paper make a note of it's usage

Comment: Ok, we're getting closer. Which value in explain() tells me how often an index is being used?

Comment: It is within the `queryPlanner.winningPlan.inputStage.indexName` field

Comment: @Sammaye I upgraded my mongodb, but I can't find the requested value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, so this is how I would do it.

First you need a list of all your indexes for a certain collection (this will be done collection by collection). Let's say we are monitoring the `user` collection to see which indexes are useless.

So I run a `db.user.getIndexes()` and this results in a parsable output of JSON (you can run this via `command()` from the client side as well to integrate with a script).

So you now have a list of your indexes. It is merely a case of understanding which queries use which indexes. If that index is not hit at all you know it is useless.

Now, you need to run every query with `explain()` from that output you can judge which index is used and match it to and index gotten from `getIndexes()`.

So here is a sample output:

```
> db.user.find({religion:1}).explain()
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "meetapp.user",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "religion" : {
                                "$eq" : 1
                        }
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                        "religion" : NumberLong(1)
                                },
                                "indexName" : "religion_1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "religion" : [
                                                "[1.0, 1.0]"
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "ip-172-30-0-35",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "3.0.0",
                "gitVersion" : "a841fd6394365954886924a35076691b4d149168"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

There are a set of rules that the `queryPlanner` field will use and you will need to discover and write for them but this first one is simple enough.

As you can see: the winning plan (in `winningPlan`) is a single (could be multiple remember, this stuff you will need to code around) `IXSCAN` (index scan) and the key pattern for the index used is:

```
"keyPattern" : {
    "religion" : NumberLong(1)
},
```

Great, now we can match that the key output of `getIndexes()`:

```
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "religion" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "name" : "religion_1",
            "ns" : "meetapp.user"
    },
```

to tells us that the `religion` index is not useless and is in fact used.

Unfortunately this is the best way I can see. It used to be that MongoDB had an index stat for number of times the index was hit but it seems that data has been removed.

So you would just rinse and repeat this process for every collection you have until you have removed the indexes that are useless.

One other way of doing this, of course, is to remove all indexes and then re-add indexes as you test your queries. Though that might be bad if you do need to do this in production.

On a side note: the best way to fix this problem is to not have it at all.

I make this easier for me by using a indexing function within my active record. Once every so often I run (from PHP) something of the sort: `./yii index/rebuild` which essentially goes through my active record models and detects which indexes I no longer use and have removed from my app and removes them in turn. It will, of course, create new indexes.

Comment: Thnak you. At least I can find out hwat Indexes are used.

Comment: Do you remember, which version was capable of an index stat for number of times the index was hit?

Comment: @PhilippSander I think like 1.6 I would really recommend not downgrading. If they removed it (which seems the case) they did for a good reason, most likely some clause made the stat useless